# Effective Python equivalent of this simple promise-chaining JavaScript class

Tags: python-3.x, promise, queue, python-asyncio

Here's the JavaScript code:

```js
class TaskQueue {
  constructor() {
    this._chain = Promise.resolve();
  }
  postTask(task) {
    const result = this._chain.then(task);
    this._chain = result.catch(() => {});
    return result;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this just takes a task (function), gets the Promise from it, ignores the errors, and adds it onto the class 'chain'. I'm not quite sure exactly why, though. [Here's the file](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/TaskQueue.js) in question, and [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/Page.js#L917) is where you can find it being used. In the usage it seems like there's really no need for queuing system to me.

I have no clue what do in Python. I'm aware that there is no 'exact' equivalent to this style of Python code, but I'd like to replicate it effectively, or at least achieve the same results as the JS even if by a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` creates a new promise which runs after the old one resolves. In Python you can create a task whose coroutine awaits the previous one. Something like:

```py
class TaskQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        fut = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
        fut.set_result(None)
        self._task = fut

    def post_task(self, awaitable):
        async def run_awaitable(prev):
            try:
                await prev
                await awaitable
            except:
                pass  # consider at least logging here
        self._task = asyncio.create_task(run_awaitable(self._task))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you assign the output of `prev` to `result`?

Comment: @MattM. Fixed now, the `result` variable remained from a previous version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a Javacript Promise copy:

```
class Promise:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.resolved = ''
        self.rejected = ''
        if callable(callback):
            callback(self.resolve, self.reject)

    def resolve(self, value):
        self.resolved = value

    def reject(self, value):
        self.rejected = value

    def then(self, callback):
        if not self.rejected:
            self.resolved = callback(self.resolved)
        return self

    def catch(self, callback):
        if self.rejected:
            self.rejected = callback(self.rejected)
        return self

    def all(self, promises):
        resolvedArray = []
        rejectedArray = []
        for promise in promises:
            promise(self.resolve, self.reject)
            if self.resolved:
                resolvedArray += self.resolved
            if self.rejected:
                rejectedArray += self.rejected
                break
        self.resolved = resolvedArray
        self.rejected = rejectedArray
        return self


def myPromise1(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Ana'])


def myPromise2(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Bia'])


def myPromise3(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Carlos'])


def myPromise4(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Daniel'])


def allResolve(values):
    print('without error: ', values)


def allReject(values):
    print('with error: ', values)


p = Promise([])
p.all([myPromise1, myPromise2]).then(allResolve).catch(allReject)
```

Another example:

```
def myPromise(resolve, reject):
    resolve(['Ana', 'Bia', 'Carlos', 'Daniel'])


def firstResolve(value):
    return value[0]


def secondResolve(value):
    print(value)


def firstReject(value):
    print('error:', value)


p = Promise(myPromise)
p.then(firstResolve).then(secondResolve).catch(firstReject)
```